# Duplicated entries when recursively creating new objects and storing their references

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a interface `Article` which contains a field with an array of `Article`. I now have a similar class which should contain the same data and references. My goal is now to create an object for each `Article` and their references.

```
interface Article{
    title:string;
    sections:Array<Article>;
}

class ArticleClass{
    constructor(article:Article) {
        buildRefs(this, article);
    }

    sections:Array<ArticleClass>;

    buildRefs(parent: ArticleClass, data: Article): void {
        data.sections.forEach((s) => {
            const nextParent = new ArticleClass(s);
            this.buildRefs(nextParent, s);
            parent.sections.push(nextParent);
        });
    }
}


// Example
const articleData = {
    title:"Main Article",
    sections:[
        {title: "1.1", sections:[]},
        {title: "1.2", sections:[{title: "1.2.1", sections:[]},{title: "1.2.2", 
        sections:[]},]},
        {title: "1.3", sections:[]},,
    ];

    const mainArticle = new ArticleClass(articleData);
}
```

In the constructor I recursively create all the objects and save the references of the current level in the `sections` array.

However when I run this, for some reason, the articles `1.2.1` and `1.2.2` are duplicated. Everything is is the right place though, only those two are duplicated.

Comment: with multiple `sections`, the `section` is pushed into the parent in the constructor call to `buildRefs()` and then again in the recursive call to the same method.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I fixed the typo. 
But wouldn't that mean the the first article should be duplicated? which is not the case

Comment: no, because with an empty `sections` it never recurses.

Comment: not sure if I can follow, the first iteration should be pushing `1.1` to the section which is correct

Comment: ah ok, now I understand. because I call it in the ctor so it runs everytime I create an object.